# How do you select any child element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
div > a{

}
```

applies properties to `<a>` child. But how can I select any type of element, not just `<a>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should select all direct child objects of all DIVs.

```
div > * {
}
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396069/how-do-you-select-any-child-element/19396087#19396087)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below.

```
div > * {
  Your css attributes should be here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following...

```
div > * {}
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396069/how-do-you-select-any-child-element/19396087#19396087)