# Elem.querySelector's immediate child

Tags: css, selector

I'm hoping to get an immediate child of an element, let's say the child should have the class `center`. I found it doesn't work like this: `elem.querySelector('>.center')`, however, it works like this:`elem.querySelector('div>.center')`. But I don't want to limit the current element type to be a div. So is there any way I can get a `.center` immediate child regardless whatever the parent is?

Comment: Reverse the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19396069/215552

Comment: `elem.querySelector` will return the first element found, not a collection, so it should be ok for your case to use `.center`, unless the element has a chance not to be found and that you want a null result in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the universal selector `*` to get an immediate child with the class `.center` regardless of the parent element.

```
elem.querySelector('* > .center')
```